# Does an Oracle get bonus spells AND revelations every second level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-advancement, oracle

I'm building an Oracle for an upcoming campaign and I'm somewhat new to Pathfinder. If you The [explanation of mysteries](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries) says I get bonus spells every other level. However, I also get another revelation at the same levels. Do I get both a bonus spell and another revelation at 2, 4, 6, etc. or do I only get the bonus spell?

For example, let's say I start out with the [Life mystery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/life) and choose to get Channel at level 1. At level 2, do I get only Detect Undead or do I get Detect Undead **and** Energy Body (for example)?

Answer (score 4):

From the 'revelations' description:

> At 1st level, 3rd level, and every four levels thereafter (7th, 11th, and so on), an oracle uncovers a new secret about her mystery that grants her powers and abilities.

At level 2 you would normally only get Detect Undead, because you don't normally get revelations every other level starting at level 2.

If you *did* get revelations at those levels by house rule or something, you would get both.  You certainly *can* get more than one class feature per level, you just don't normally do so in theis specific case.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

The bonus spells are labelled as **Mystery Spell** on the [Oracle's Table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle).

Your [Mystery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle#TOC-Mystery) is chosen at first level, and you also learn a [Revelation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle#TOC-Revelation) at same level. But after that you will have to follow the table to see when you gain another, *mystery/bonus spells* every even levels (2, 4, 6, 8, etc), and new *revelations* at 3rd and every four levels after 3rd (1, 3, 7, 11, 15, and 19).

If you look closely, you will never obtan a bonus spell and revelation at the same level, but that's designed like that, so you have few levels were you class will "*give you nothing, but spells*".

If you do think you need more *revelations*, you can look up the feat [Extra Revelation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-revelation-1), or the [Ring of Revelation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-revelation).